# Different stationarity of time series

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, stationarity, differencing

I am testing stationarity of multiple time series so I can run multiple regression later. My results are mixed. The variables that I plan to be my dependent variables are non-stationary at level, by stationary in first order. On the other hand, most of the independent variables are either stationary at level or intercept only. I have only one variable that is stationary at level at all three specifications (none, trend and intercept).

Should I transform all my variables in first order so I get proper interpretation when running a regression? What is your advice?

Comment: Do not difference variables that are stationary. Otherwise, you will run into the problem of overdifferencing.

Comment: @RichardHardy but I need all variabels stationary. I can't use variables  from level and variables from first differences together.

Comment: Why not? This is not an unusual thing to do.